# How to pass data from master page server side to another aspx page client side in ajax in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, master-pages, client-side, server-side

I want to pass value from master page server side to another aspx page client side in ajax in asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this-

In master page -

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "MyFunction()", true);
            }

<script type="text/javascript">
        function MyFunction()
        {
            alert('my master page function');
            window.MyPageFunction(10);
        }
    </script>
```

In content page-

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    window.MyPageFunction = function (input) {
        alert(input);
    };
</script>
```